# Prove $f(a)|f(b)$ for infinitely many positive integers $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image: problem]

The author has written
$$b=a+k|f(a)|$$
Without any motivation, I am having trouble understanding, how he defined $b $ in this way.

My approach:
For,$$f(a)|f(b)$$
$$f(b)=kf(a)$$
Here we can rewrite the equation as
$$f(b)-f(a)=(k-1)f(a)$$
Now as $b-a$ divides $f(b)-f(a)$
We can write $f(b)-f(a)$ =$m(b-a)$.
But I couldn't make further progress using this approach.
Thanks

Comment: *Hint*: Since $b-a\mid f(b)-f(a)$ it suffices to choose $b$ such that $f(a)\mid b-a$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it as $f(a)$ will always divide itself the given condition is equivalent of saying $f(a)| f(b)$